# How to call jquery plugin function using `onlick attribute` in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Just as we call regular javascript functions from `onclick` attribute, why can't we call jQuery methods as shown in the following code. Why does this not work?

```
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
  <p id="p1">Some Text inside paragraph</p>
  <button type="button" onclick="$.test();">Click Me</button>
</body>
```

JS

```
$.fn.extend({
  test: function() {
    var t = $('#p1').text();
    alert(t);
    });
  },
});
```

thanks
bt

Comment: Why would you do such a thing to begin with? Stop using inline javascript, and a proper event handler instead.

Comment: and FYI, you don't have a `$.test();` method, you have a `$(element).test()` method!

Comment: You're mixing your extensions vs plugins.  You *can* do it this way, by using `onlick='$(this).test();'`

Comment: @freedomn-m yes you are right.. I misunderstood the result

Comment: @adeneo, can you pls explain difference between `$.test();` method, and `$(element).test()`.

Comment: Sure, one is defined as `$.test = function()` the other is defined as `$.prototype.test = function()`, but jQuery shortens that to `$.fn.test = function()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the issue of using `onclick=` aside, you can do it this way:

```
<p id="p1">Some Text inside paragraph</p>
<button type="button" onclick="$(this).test();">Click Me</button>
```

and

```
$.fn.extend({
  test: function() {
    var t = $(this).text();   // use $(this) here
    alert(t);
  },
});
```

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/asw8824h/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click',"#target",function () {        
        // do something
    });
});
```